# How do I use jquery validate remote validation to set and return form field values to the form action page?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-validate

I have a form that validates using the jQuery plugin: Validation, v1.9.0. The validation also performs remote calls to a server side script (Coldfusion) to check user names, email addresses, etc..

My problem is this:

During the remote validation process, there are times when new form fields will be defined and set through the server side script which need to be returned to the calling form so that they can be passed to the form's action page.

As you'll notice in my code snippets below, I am having to walk these form field values through each step of the process (i.e., creating a result structure, picking those up in the success handler, etc.) which is both tedious, and prone to errors as the form may change in the future.

Is there a method I can use which will simply allow me to "globally" set these form field values which my calling form/action page can pickup through once the form validates?

**JQUERY VALIDATION SNIPPET:**

```
validator = $('#cartDownload_form').validate({

  submitHandler: function(form) {

  // make submit button disabled
  $('#submit_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  // show modal dialog about submittal process..
  var processing_dialog = ShowDialog("Processing Order...", "<p>Please wait while we process your order...</p>", false);

  // prepare Options Object 
  var options = { 
    url: "/products/val_cartDownload_remote.cfm", 
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) { 

      if(data.ERRORMESSAGELIST.length == 0) {
        // no errors...

        // set return form field values needed for action page
        $('#verified').val(data.VERIFIED);
        $('#dlurl').val(data.DLURL);
        $('#dllocation').val(data.DLLOCATION);
        $('#itemname').val(data.ITEMNAME);
        $('#itemtease').val(data.ITEMTEASE);
        $('#itemimage').val(data.ITEMIMAGE);
        $('#itemimage_border').val(data.ITEMIMAGE_BORDER);
        $('#itemimage_alt').val(data.ITEMIMAGE_ALT);
        $('#itemimage_title').val(data.ITEMIMAGE_TITLE);
        $('#itemthumb').val(data.ITEMTHUMB);
        $('#itemthumb_border').val(data.ITEMTHUMB_BORDER);
        $('#itemthumb_alt').val(data.ITEMTHUMB_ALT);
        $('#itemthumb_title').val(data.ITEMTHUMB_TITLE);
        $('#itempubnotes').val(data.ITEMPUBNOTES);
        $('#itemurl_size').val(data.ITEMURL_SIZE);  
        $('#first_name').val(data.FIRST_NAME);  

        // submit the form
        $('#cartDownload_form')[0].submit();  

        return true;

      } else {
        // an error occurred...

  }; 

  $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);

  return false;
}
```

**REMOTE VALIDATION SNIPPET (these are new form fields and values not in calling form):**

```
    <cfset variables.result_struct = {
  errorfieldlist = listtoarray(form.errorfieldlist),
  errormessagelist = listtoarray(form.errormessagelist, form.RS),
  verified = form.verified,
  dlurl = form.dlurl,
  dllocation = form.dllocation,
  itemname = form.itemname,
  itemtease = form.itemtease,
  itemimage = form.itemimage,
  itemimage_border = form.itemimage_border,
  itemimage_alt = form.itemimage_alt,
  itemimage_title = form.itemimage_title,
  itemthumb = form.itemthumb,
  itemthumb_border = form.itemthumb_border,
  itemthumb_alt = form.itemthumb_alt,
  itemthumb_title = form.itemthumb_title,
  itempubnotes = form.itempubnotes,
  itemurl_size = form.itemurl_size,
  first_name = form.first_name
}>

<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(result_struct)#</cfoutput>
```

So what I'm trying to get away from is having to set all of these form field values manually in several places simply to get them back to my calling form/action page.

I'm probably making a simply rookie mistake and I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. What's the purpose of your validation snippet? It doesn't validate the submitted values. It just copies them from the form struct in your result_struct.

Comment: I'm just providing snippets for the purpose of this question. The validation at this point has already occurred and I'm trying to get the new form field values back to the calling page/action page WITHOUT having to define each value along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify your jQuery:

```
if(data.ERRORMESSAGELIST.length == 0) {
// no errors...
// set return form field values needed for action page
    for (field in data)        {
      $('#' + field.toLowerCase()).val(data[field]);
    }

    // submit the form
    $('#cartDownload_form')[0].submit();
```

And your cf code:

```
  <cfset variables.result_struct = {
    errorfieldlist = listtoarray(form.errorfieldlist),
    errormessagelist = listtoarray(form.errormessagelist, form.RS)
  }>
  <cfset StructAppend(variables.result_struct, form)>

<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(result_struct)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Told 'ya I was making a rookie mistake! That's awesome Jake. Exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly.

Comment: Also, I'm somewhat new to StackOverflow, so if I need to award points or something, let me know. Thanks again jake.

Comment: Well, accepting the answer is a good way to award points.  Also, upvoting works.

Comment: Cool. I tried to upvote but my rep score is too low. Thanks Jake.

Comment: Jake, I'm now noticing that my error handling is broken. If I take out the structappend(), it works, so I think my error handler needs to be revised to accommodate this new return. Here is my error handler snippet:

Comment: // prepare errors for validator
            var errors = {};
            $.each(data.ERRORFIELDLIST, function(i, val) {
              eval("errors."+val+"='"+data[i]+"'");
            });
            
            // prepare error messages for dialog
            var dialog_html = '<ul>';
            $.each(data.ERRORMESSAGELIST, function(i, val) {
              dialog_html += '<li><span style="color:#cd0a0a;">'+val+'</span></li>';
            }); dialog_html += '</ul>';

Comment: What do I need to do to allow the structappend() data without breaking the above? Thanks.

Comment: please update your question with the results of the #SerializeJSON(result_struct)#, both when the StructAppend is present and when it is not.

Comment: I think the issue is happening due to the remote validation snippet.

Comment: Response BEFORE: while(1);{"ERRORMESSAGELIST":["Please enter a valid <strong>password<\/strong> (hint: it's case sensitive).","Don't forget, if you need help at any time, please don't hesitate to <strong>click the 'Contact Support' button below<\/strong> for an immediate reponse. Thanks!"],"ERRORFIELDLIST":["password"]}

Comment: Response AFTER: while(1);{"ITEMTHUMB_TITLE":"","ERRORMESSAGELIST":"Please enter a valid <strong>password<\/strong> (hint: it's case sensitive).|Don't forget, if you need help at any time, please don't hesitate to <strong>click the 'Contact Support' button below<\/strong> for an immediate reponse. Thanks!","ITEMIMAGE_BORDER":"","CARTDOWNLOADKEY":"3E79F997-B4F8-E420-050A7ECBD0442674","ITEMURL_SIZE":"","FIELDNAMES":"VERIFIED,DLURL,DLLOCATION,ITEMNAME,ITEMTEASE,ITEMIMAGE ...

Comment: It looks like the Response AFTER format is missing brackets, etc.? []

Comment: Maybe ERRORFIELDLIST and ERRORMESSAGE list are no longer in an array?

Comment: Please re-read my last comment - I need to see the JSON output.  And please update your answer, above, rather than reply in comments.  Easier to format / read that way.

Comment: I provided the edit, but StackOverflow says it is under peer review .. whatever that means.

Comment: Hi Jake, I don't see my edits anymore. Did they take them off?

Comment: Jake, I re-posted this issue as a new question since I can't seem to get it posted here. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651565/jquery-validate-remote-return-structure-issue